# Doubts in understanding the elastic property of matter

Tags: condensed-matter, potential-energy, material-science, elasticity

Here the graph of potential energy and force produced due to interaction between two atoms are given . And at a particular separation between the atoms, they have their minimum potential energy. And in the second paragraph, the lines which I have underlined writes that all the atoms tend to keep their separation at that particular value which has minimum potential energy. I am unable to understand this. I mean what does this line says?

[image]

Is it that separation between every atom in a material at stable or unstrerched or undeformed state the particular value of separation which keeps the potential energy minimum? And if so then why is the value is same for a material containing large number of atoms where every atom interact with each other, whereas that value gives the required separation for minimum potential energy only when interaction is between two atoms.

Comment: The equilibrium sepration between the atoms is not the same in the two cases. In larger atoms system, you will need to include interactions in 3d and also the higher order ( but smaller) interaction terms in the potential energy expression.

Comment: Is your question about elasticity or about the difference between a single bond and a macroscopic system?

Comment: @Mathieu Bouville basically it is the difference between a single bond and a macroscopic system